# Write a C function to evaluate the series // sin(x) = x-(x3 /3!)+(x5 /5!)-(x7 /7!)+... // up to 10 terms

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int series(float,float);

int main()

{

    float x,n,series_value;
    printf("Enter the value of x: ");
    scanf("%f",&x);
    printf("\nEnter the value of n: ");
    scanf("%f",&n);
    series_value=series(x,n);
    printf("\nValue of series sin (%.2f) is: %f\n",x,series_value);
    return 0;
}

int series(float x,float n)

{

    int i,sum=0,sign=-1;
    int j,fact=1,p=1;
    for (i=1; i<=(2*n)-1; i+=2)
    {
        for (j=1; j<=i; j++)
        {
        p=p*x;
        fact=fact*j;
        }
        sign=-1*sign;
        sum=sum + sign*p/fact;       
    }
    return (sum);
}
```

Output: 
Enter the value of x: 5

Enter the value of n: 10
(lldb) 
and this message 
**Thread 1: EXC_ARITHMETIC (code=EXC_I386_DIV, subcode=0x0)**
[![Thread 1 Queue : com.apple.main-thread (serial)
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afLIu.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afLIu.png)

Why is this message coming? and what is wrong in the program as answer is not coming right

Comment: You're overflowing `fact`. 13! is 0 mod 2^31.

Answer (score 1):

There is a few problems with your code. As @PaulHankin said, when `fact` overflows and becoms zero, you will have a division by zero, and "weird things" happen.

Your factorial and power calculation is also wrong. You are recalculating it in each iteration of the outer loop without reseting `fact` and `p` first:

```
fact = 1; // You need to reset fact and p to its start value here
p = 1;
for (j=1; j<=i; j++)
  {
    p=p*x;
    fact=fact*j;
  }
```

Your third problem is that for your function calculate the correct value for `sin`, which is not an integer value, you need to use `float`, or even better `double`, when calculating `sum`. So `sum` must be declared `float`, and the division `p/fact` must use float division. By also declaring `p` and `fact` as float, you will solve both the overflow issue, and use the correct division. Naturally your function must also return  a `float`

```
float series(float x,float n)
{
    int i,sign=-1;
    int j, 
    float sum = 0;
    float fact = 1;
    float p = 1;
    for (i=1; i<=(2*n)-1; i+=2)
    {
        fact = 1;
        p = 1;
        for (j=1; j<=i; j++)
        {
           p=p*x;
           fact=fact*j;
        }
        sign=-1*sign;
        sum=sum + sign*p/fact;       
    }
    return (sum);
}
```

This code still has a minor problem. By having an inner loop, it is slower than necessary. Since this probably is homework, I am not getting rid of that loop for you, just giving you a hint: You don't have to recalculate `fact` from scratch on each iteration of the outer loop, just try to find out how `fact` changes from one iteration to the next. The same goes for `p`.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Series of Sinx

#include<stdio.h>

#include<math.h>

#define ACCURACY 0.0001

int factorial(int n);

int main()
{
    float x,sum,term;
    int i,power;

    printf("Enter value of X: ");
    scanf("%f",&x);

    i=1;
    power=3;
    sum=x;
    term=x;

    while(term>=ACCURACY)
    {
        term = pow(x,power) / factorial(power);

        if(i%2==1)
        {
            sum -= term;
        }
        else
        {
            sum += term;
        }

        power+=2;
        i++;
    }
    printf("sin(%f) = %.6f\n",x,sum);
    
    return 0;
}

int factorial(int n){
    int i=n,fact=1;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        fact=fact*i;
    }
    return fact;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don’t just leave large blocks of code. Instead, also offer an explanation of what you’re doing.

Answer (score 0):

plenty bugs. To do not caclulate the fact values all the time they are in the lookup table

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double series(double,int);

long long fact[] = { 1, 2, 6, 24,
                     120, 720, 5040, 40320,
                     362880, 3628800, 39916800, 479001600,
                     6227020800, 87178291200, };

double mypow(double x, unsigned p)
{
    double result = x;
    while(p && --p)
        result *= x;
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    for(double x = 0; x <= M_PI + M_PI / 60; x += M_PI / 30)
        printf("Value of series sin (%.2f) is: %f\n",x,series(x, 5));
    fflush(stdout);
}


double series(double x,int n)
{
    double sum = x;
    int i,sign=1;
    for (i=3; i<=(2*n)-1; i+=2)
    {
        sign=-1*sign;
        sum += sign*(mypow(x, i)/fact[i -1]);
    }
    return (sum);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/U6dULN

Answer (score -1):

maybe its due to floating-point exception as u have declared that the function should return int type value
int series(float,float);//hear 
so u can try editing the return type of this function as float 
Note:-also u need to change at function definition and the datatype of 
  *int* i,sum=0,sign=-1;
    *int* j,fact=1,p=1;
to float as it is returning the value (sum) which should also be float

Comment: thanks!! I correccted the int-float contradictions and its working now